# ToolTip odd behavior

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have this code

```
Private Sub PortField_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles PortField.KeyPress
    If (Not IsNumeric(e.KeyChar)) Then
        e.KeyChar = ChrW(0)
        ToolTip1.Show("N'entrez que des chiffres, merci.", PortField, 103, 10, 1000)
    End If
End Sub
```

So  when the event is fired (writting a letter) it should display a tooltip at the location I asked.

The problem is the tooltip, when I click a single time on a letter key appear like this
[image: Wrong one]

But when I double click a letter key it appear like this
[image: Good one]

So I don,t understand why it's not working and I could use some help thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call it twice, first time emtpy:

```
ToolTip1.Show(String.Empty, PortField, 0)
ToolTip1.Show("N'entrez que des chiffres, merci.", PortField, 103, 10, 1000)
```

Comment: Why not... It should work, if you think of another idea could you notify me because I don't know I don't really like it, in my opinion it's sloppy but I will use it until someone else find something or if I find the problem :/

Comment: @Mokmeuh It was a known bug at Microsoft Connect.  They obviously never fixed it.